# Sharepoint 2013 Navigation show pages is greyed out

Tags: sharepoint, navigation

I have encountered the following problem in Sharepoint 2013: when I go to Site Settings -> Look And Feel -> Navigation the **Show pages** option below **Structural Navigation: Display the navigation items below the current site** is greyed out and cannot be selected.

I have enabled the **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure** feature and I am working with the top-level site.

I tried to check Sow pages from within a subsite but it's also greyed out.

Can you help me solve the problem?

Thank you in advance.

**LATER EDIT**

I've also enabled **Sharepoint Server Publishing** from **Site Settings->Site Actions->Manage site features** and now it's working